# Is it possible to log on with a user with an application that is started on windows starup?

Tags: c#, winlogon

In a computer, I have a gRPC service that is hosted in a console application.

This console application is started when the system starts. For that, I used a schedule task thas starts the console application with the user A and I set to start on startup, no need the user log on. So the console application starts when system starts, not when the log on of the user.

Then, the state of the computer is in the log on screen and the gRPC service started. I would like to know if there is some way in C# to log on into the user A, perhaps with a command line or powershell command.

The idea it is log on in the user remotely from a mobile application.

Thanks.